# Add a custom attribute in grid customer magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, customer-grid

I have created an attribute type: select but i can't display it in the grid customer.
the code of my customer_listing.xml

```
<column name="customer_status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Status</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">190</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

the code of the UpgradeData.php

```
$attributeCode7 = "customer_status";
    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode7, [
        'type'              => 'varchar',
        'label'             => 'Customer Status',
        'input'             => 'select',
        'source'            => 'Stack\Customer\Model\Attribute\Source\CustomerStatus',
        'required'          => true,
        'visible'           => true,
        'user_defined'      => true,
        'sort_order'        => 1000,
        'position'          => 1000,
        'system'            => false,
        'is_used_in_grid'       => true,
        'is_visible_in_grid'    => true,

    ]);

    $attribute7 = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode7)
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' =>  ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']
        ]);
    $attribute7->save();
```

also i created indexer.xml under etc of my module here is the code:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
<indexer id="customer_grid">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="customer_status" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="int"/>
    </fieldset>
</indexer>
```

please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need `customer_listing.xml` or `indexer.xml`  to show customer attribute in gird. these line will do it for you

```
    'is_used_in_grid'       => true,
    'is_visible_in_grid'    => true,
```

Just run the following command. This will show your column in grid.

```
 php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Make sure **Customer Grid index rebuilt** `Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully`

New column of `customer_status` will be created `customer_grid_flat` table

Comment: thanks for your replay but i really put those two in the upgrade but nothing displayed

Comment: @DevelopperMagento did you run the command? make sure your you have entry in  table `eav_attribute` and respectively `customer_eav_attribute`

Comment: yes i have the entry in customer_entity_varchar and the attribute is displayed in eav_attribute and when i click on add new user in BO

Comment: 'type'              => 'varchar',
            'label'             => 'Customer Status',
            'input'             => 'select',
            'source'            => '...',
            'required'          => true,
            'visible'           => true,
            'sort_order'        => 1000,
            'position'          => 1000,
            'system'            => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,

        ]);

Comment: @DevelopperMagento run this command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` and make sure column `customer_status` is created.

Comment: yes it's created and i can  choose an options and it's saved and i can find the value in customer_entity_varchar

Comment: but not displayed in the grid

Comment: @DevelopperMagento maybe cache issue logout and login to admin panel and check. this is last thing you have to make sure of it.

Comment: @DevelopperMagento, Did you select to show your custom attribute collumn ??!! From all collumn list at customer Grid.

Comment: @Vivek forgot about that thanks for reminding me.

Comment: not displayed :(

Comment: so what do i have to do now and Vivek i did not understand your  note

Comment: @QaisarSatti please  can you suggest t me another way to fix this

Comment: @DevelopperMagento there is a drop down of `column` above the grid make sure you checked your column.

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeees i can now see my attribute but i don't want to find some othersattribute when exporting the list

Comment: how to add value in new customer custom attribute?