# Showing Customer Attribute in Customer Grid

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, attributes, grid, customer-attribute

I created the customer attribute in Magneto but it is not showing in Customer grid i need to show it without deleting the current attribute. How can i do it.

**My code** 
**InstallData.php**

```
namespace Sm\CutomerNumberAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    private $eavConfig;

    private $attributeResource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, "customer_number");

        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_number', [
            // Attribute parameters
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Customer Number',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 500,
            'position' => 500,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_number');
        $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
        $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);

        /*
        //You can use this attribute in the following forms
        adminhtml_checkout
        adminhtml_customer
        adminhtml_customer_address
        customer_account_create
        customer_account_edit
        customer_address_edit
        customer_register_address
        */


        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);

        $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: here is the solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250944/add-a-custom-attribute-in-grid-customer-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

Check below code

**InstallData.php**:- sets up data when the module is installed.

> **File**:-Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;

/**
 * Class InstallData
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $customerSetupFactory;
    protected $indexerRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_number', [
            'group' => 'General',
            'type' => 'static',
            'label' => 'Customer Number',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'position' => 100,
            'used_in_grid' => true,
            'visible_in_grid' => true,
            'searchable_in_grid' => true,
            'filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $custNumberAttr = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_number');
        $custNumberAttr->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'checkout_register',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit',
                'adminhtml_checkout'
            ]
        )->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1);

        $custNumberAttr->setData('is_used_in_grid', true);
        $custNumberAttr->setData('is_visible_in_grid', true);
        $custNumberAttr->setData('is_filterable_in_grid', true);
        $custNumberAttr->save();
        $indexer = $this->indexerRegistry->get(Customer::CUSTOMER_GRID_INDEXER_ID);
        $indexer->invalidate();
    }
}
```

**UpgradeData.php**:- modifies data after the module is installed when the
module version is upgraded

> **File**:- Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeData.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;

/**
 * Class UpgradeData
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $customerSetupFactory;
    protected $indexerRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if ($context->getVersion()
            && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1') < 0
        ) {
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_number', [
                'type' => 'static',
                'label' => 'Customer Number',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'position' => 100,
                'used_in_grid' => true,
                'visible_in_grid' => true,
                'searchable_in_grid' => true,
                'filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);

            $custNumberAttr = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_number');
            $custNumberAttr->setData(
                'used_in_forms',
                ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout']
            )->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                ->setData("is_system", 0)
                ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                ->setData("is_visible", 1);

            $custNumberAttr->setData('is_used_in_grid',true);
            $custNumberAttr->setData('is_visible_in_grid',true);
            $custNumberAttr->setData('is_filterable_in_grid',true);
            $custNumberAttr->save();
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**output**:-

[image]

I hope this will help you