# How to add custom attributes to Customer Export? (from the import/export admin page -> Customers Main File)

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes, export, importexport

I need to add custom attributes to the **Customers Main File** export (from the *Import / Export* admin page), but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I believe I can create a preference to override `\Magento\CustomerImportExport\Model\Export\Customer::_permanentAttributes[]` to add the codes of my custom attributes, but it's not something I can do when there's hundreds of custom attributes, and new attributes are added and should be automatically available for export.

So is there a way to make it so that all custom attributes are available to filter and to export on this export page?

Answer (score 0):

When you had created the custom attribute for customer make sure you made it visible for customer grid.
Add these too line in your installData script

```
'is_used_in_grid'       => true,
'is_visible_in_grid'    => true,
```

Your can check this out for more : [Add a custom attribute in grid customer magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250944/add-a-custom-attribute-in-grid-customer-magento-2)

After that you can see your custom attribute in the coloum. **Check your custom attribute and then export**.

[image: Magento 2 Coloumns]

Comment: As I said, I was talking about the `import / export -> Customer Main File` grid and not the `All Customers` grid.