# How can we add custom customer attributes in admin grid

Tags: admin, magento2.4, customer-attribute, customer-grid

I have created an attribute type: Test but I want to display in the grid customer.

https://prnt.sc/aRyraGEP7kKf

Comment: Take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250944/add-a-custom-attribute-in-grid-customer-magento-2

Comment: I am using customer attribute module for custom attributes.

Comment: @kiran you have created customer attribute using UpradeData.php Or using any module to create attribute?

Comment: I am not using UpgradeData.php

Comment: Using module to create attributes

Comment: Is there any option of "Appearance in Customer Grid"  in the module? Or can you please share the module name which you are using. Please add some more clarification, so we can understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `customer_listing.xml`

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <listingToolbar name="listing_top"/>
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="company_name" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerAttribute">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Column Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Then create `CustomerAttribute.php`

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/CustomerAttribute.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class CustomerAttribute extends Column
{
    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item)
            {
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($item['entity_id']);
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $customer->getCompanyName();
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Change **`customer_attribute_name`** according to yours

Hope this will help you!
Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: field is visible in grid but value is not visible in customer grid.
https://prnt.sc/fnA0L3pwrHf0

Comment: @kiran you used above code? If yes then please share attribute_code I'll update the answer accordingly

Comment: Attribute code : company_name

Comment: @kiran I have updated my answer please try again and it will work for you. Please use the above code

Comment: Thank you so much Arun Sharma

Comment: above code working now.

Comment: can we display same attribute in frontend?

Comment: @kiran yes we can display it on frontend also, where do you want to display it on frontend. Create a new question for it