# Can we add custom fields to "Edit" Customer form using ui-components?

Tags: customer-attribute, magento2.4.6

I came accross this link https://webkul.com/blog/tab-with-form-in-admin-customer-edit-magento-2/ , but here they have not used ui_components.I want to add one enable/disable field and one "number" input field alongside a checkbox.How can i do it.And how can i retrieve values from these fields to apply checks at checkout or save them in database.

Comment: You can try this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250944/add-a-custom-attribute-in-grid-customer-magento-2